# How to freeze layer parameters in Flux.jl

Tags: julia, flux.jl

I am currently working on a transfer learning problem so I would like to freeze most of my layers such that the model is not re-trained, and only the final layer's weights are modified. How can I choose which layers to freeze with Flux.jl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flux provides a simple interface to do this which is to only pass in the layers you want to be modified to the `Flux.params()` function as shown below:

```
m = Chain(
      Dense(784, 64, relu),
      Dense(64, 64, relu),
      Dense(32, 10)
    )

ps = Flux.params(m[3:end])
```

In the above example, we chose to only update the final `Dense` layer (which is commonly what you do in a transfer learning example).

You can see a full example with more build up in the Flux.jl tutorial on transfer learning: https://fluxml.ai/tutorials/2020/10/18/transfer-learning.html